# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

i want to run this code but i can't and received this error.
also i downloaded pandas package.

```py
import pandas

data = {
    "Day": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "Visitors": [18, 26, 18, 18, 9, 9, 20, 30, 16, 24],
    "Bounce_Rate": [77.27, 74.07, 73.68, 65, 90, 70, 72, 62.16, 81.25, 72],
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: is it me or does the bounce_rate list look longer than the rest? there is no error message posted in ur question. could u add that

Comment: I did not get your error, but I think you missed a comma after the `Visitors` array. It then worked fine for me.

Comment: What is the file name of this script?

Answer (score 31):

Have you have saved your file as `pandas.py`? It will confuse the [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) if the file is named `pandas.py`
Otherwise check if there is any file named pandas and delete it. So that you can definitely succeed in fixing this.

Comment: I had named a file `csv.py` and this happened.

Comment: I named my file `copy.py` xD

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an attribute error, this means the program is not recognizing the pandas library. Is there another variable you named pandas? Or a directory or file you have named pandas?

Comment: That would have raised a `SyntaxError`, not an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the name of your python script was 'pandas.py' which will cause a circular import...

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0):

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH. I'M LEARNING.

In my case, I solved the error by changing the file name.

```
# in file: csv.py 
import pandas as pd
data = {'first_name': ['Sigrid', 'Joe', 'Theodoric','Kennedy', 'Beatrix', 'Olimpia', 'Grange', 'Sallee'],
        'last_name': ['Mannock', 'Hinners', 'Rivers', 'Donnell', 'Parlett', 'Guenther', 'Douce', 'Johnstone'],
        'age': [27, 31, 36, 53, 48, 36, 40, 34],
        'amount_1': [7.17, 1.90, 1.11, 1.41, 6.69, 4.62, 1.01, 4.88],
        'amount_2': [8.06,  "?", 5.90,  "?",  "?", 7.48, 4.37,  "?"]}
datosDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(datosDataFrame)
datosDataFrame.to_csv('example.csv')
```

I get an error

```
Error: AttributeError partially initialized module 'pandas' has no 
attribute 'DataFrame' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

"Most likely due to a circular import" means any variable/name is repeated. In my case, my script `csv.py` conflicted with `csv` in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this error.  My solution and causes were different than others mentioned, so I'll offer info below.

1. I was running a cell in a jupyter notebook (filename not pandas.py but 0_isbn_get.ipynb)
2. I hadn't yet activated my virtual environment
3. Starting the virtual environment then running the cell did not fix the issue

Fix:

1. Restart the kernel
2. activate the virtual environment
3. Run the notebook cell

Answer (score -1):

please check your panda version
reinstall panda
in colab restart runtime and run all

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32468285)